# Flutter theme on textfield

Tags: flutter, colors, themes, textfield

flutter theming is going to make me crazy.

On main I set this seed color :  colorSchemeSeed: Color(0xFF6750A4)

If I personalise theme for a TextField from main.dart as shown:

```
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
        ),
```

I obtain a completely white fillColor, but if I personalise the Theme of the TextInput directly from decoration inside TextField as shown, the color used is different (and this is the color that I really want).

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
   ),),
```

This is my main.dart code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          elevation: 0,
          scrolledUnderElevation: 2,
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 16), //per settare l'altezza a 56
        ),
        colorSchemeSeed: Color(0xFF6750A4),
      
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Of course this issue is visible also with appBar theme.
Can someone help me out? I'd like to set all themes of widget (as possibile) from my main.dart, so it will be more easily in a future to change them.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Ended up extracting the color applied into a constants.dart file. So that I can manage the color's of app in a single area. 

Ex: `kTextFormFillColor=Color(0xFF0000F)`  // like this

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 
I have solved it in a similar way. In the constant.dart file I have create a ColorScheme variable with all Colors like: primaryColor : Color(…), onPrimary ….. then you can call the ColorScheme variable also in the main.dart and you can see changes.